# ImportError after installing django-waffe?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to use django-waffle in my django project, however when I try to run the project I get a `ImportError: cannot import name Flag`  I get this error when I also run syncdb or when I try to run a migration via South.  This is on Django 1.5.4/Python 2.7.1.  I have `django.core.context_processors.request` in my `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` and `waffle.middleware.WaffleMiddleware` in my `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` as per the django-waffle documentation.

From syncdb:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in 
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)

File "/Users/Dropbox/virtualenviroments/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py", line 453, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()

File "/Users/Dropbox/virtualenviroments/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)

File "/Users/Dropbox/virtualenviroments/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py", line 272, in fetch_command
    klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)

File "/Users/Dropbox/virtualenviroments/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py", line 77, in load_command_class
    module = import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name))

File "/Users/Dropbox/virtualenviroments/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    **import**(name)

File "/Users/Dropbox/virtualenviroments/lib/python2.7/site-packages/south/management/commands/**init**.py", line 10, in 
    import django.template.loaders.app_directories

File "/Users/Dropbox/virtualenviroments/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loaders/app_directories.py", line 25, in 
    raise ImproperlyConfigured('ImportError %s: %s' % (app, e.args[0]))

django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: ImportError waffle: cannot import name Flag

Comment: Please post complete traceback and the code where it's being generated.

Comment: I've had this same problem lately, and simply adding `waffle` to `settings.INSTALLED_APPS` triggers the error on any management command.